# Ionic 5 angular navigation: ion-back-button not visible

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-routing, ionic5

i have an app with a structure similar to the one I created
[on this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-navigation-problem?file=src/app/tab1/tab1-routing.module.ts).
the app have this three routes:

```
/tabs/tab1

/tab/tab2

/tab/tab2/subtab
```

I cannot understand If I'm missing something or if this is the navigation system, but when i go from `/tab/tab2` to `/tab/tab2/subpage` I can see the back button. When I go from `/tabs/tab1` to `/tab/tab2/subpage` it is not visible.
Is it normal?
I would like to see a back button to come back to `/tab/tab1`.
Thanks

Comment: Please post complete code for your various tab modules. There is not enough here to answer the question. But in general it is likely that your history stack is not consistent as these two scenarios will create two different history stacks. In the second use case /tab/tab2/subpage has no where to go since it is at top of its particular stack. The way we solved this was by implementing our own history manager and over riding ionic back handlers

Comment: Hi @E.Maggini, thanks for the answer. The code is quite long so i posted a link to a working stackblitz project so people can see and try.
Thanks for the idea of a custom history manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

tab1.html,tab2.html

`<ion-button routerLink="/subpage"></ion-button>`

`app-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    loadChildren: () => import("./tabs/tabs.module").then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: "subpage",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./subpage/subpage.module").then(m => m.SubpagePageModule)
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

`tabs-routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab1PageModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'tab2',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, thanks for answer. I tried and it's working!
I forked the project and tried you solution here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-navigation-problem-subpage-on-app

I wonder if there is a way to keep the /subpage under /tabs/tab2 (/tabs/tab2/subpage) because in our app is logically more appropriate but thanks again!

Comment: Indeed what this solution does is keep everything on the same history stack.....but as you say.....things are no longer organized according to desired logic.